# Having duplicate values in DropDownList selection cause mismatch selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DropDownList`, which is bound to the database. The values in the `DropDownList` list may be something like:

> Bedroom1
>      Bedroom2
>      Kitchen1
>      Kitchen2

When these items are list in `DropDownList`, having selected "Bedroom2", selects "Bedroom1" itself, but having selected "Kitchen2", selects "Kitchen1".

This `DropDownList` is further bound to another `DropDownList`. I have set AutoPostBack for both the `DropDownList`s. I have bound the datasource from code behind.

What might have gone wrong?

Databinding code:

```
SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM " + Label3.Text, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
myda.Fill(ds, "Table");
LOC_LIST2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
LOC_LIST2.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Location_Instance"].ColumnName.ToString(); 
LOC_LIST2.DataValueField=ds.Tables[0].Columns["Location_Type"].ColumnName.ToStri??ng(); 
LOC_LIST2.DataBind(); 
LOC_LIST2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Choose One Location---", "-1"));
```

Therefore in the above code Location_Instance is the number of locations(Location_Type) that is added and store in database and the same is retrieved in the above `DropDownList`.

This is a very serious issue, can someone please help me on this asap?

Comment: Post the code and the actual items as how they are rendered on the page.

Comment: Post that inside your post, not as an image but as a code bracket

Comment: I've have added the code the to your post.  For future reference, please use the "edit" link right below your question to add that type of information (rather than the comments, as they don't show the code very clearly).  Please also note that I fixed some other spelling and grammatical problems, and added some formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting duplicate items in your DropDownList after postback, try adding this in your binding code before setting the DropDown's DataSource:

```
LOC_LIST2.Items.Clear();
```

This will clear all items from DropDownList, then your current binding code will run and re-add the items that are required.
So, new code would read:

```
SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM " + Label3.Text, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
myda.Fill(ds, "Table");
LOC_LIST2.Items.Clear();
LOC_LIST2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
LOC_LIST2.DataTextField =     ds.Tables[0].Columns["Location_Instance"].ColumnName.ToString(); 
LOC_LIST2.DataValueField=ds.Tables[0].Columns["Location_Type"].ColumnName.ToStri??ng(); 
LOC_LIST2.DataBind(); 
LOC_LIST2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Choose One Location---", "-1"));
```

Also, on a side note you may wish to look at using parameterized SQL statements to help protect from things like SQL injection.  Example from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand.aspx

Comment: Sorry my problem is I need to get those duplicate values in `DropDownList`  >Bedroom1  >Bedroom2  But should be able to select Bedroom2,when I select it.